# Is every connected complete locally compact metric space proper?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The [Hopf-Rinow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem#Variations_and_generalizations) for metric spaces states that a length metric spaces if complete and locally compact then it is proper, i.e. every closed bounded subset is compact. I wonder whether there is a counter example if one drops the length metric requirement and adds connectedness. More precisely: If a metric space is connected complete and locally compact, then is it proper ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, consider $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$.

Note that you can do the same thing replacing $\mathbb R$ with any connected, complete, locally compact, but noncompact metric space. Since the new metric is locally isometric to the old metric, it will not change completeness, connectedness, nor local compactness, but the whole space becomes a noncompact ball of radius $1$.

Comment: It turns out that this is mentioned in the book of M. Gromov *Metric Structures for Riemannian and Non-Riemannian Spces* p. 9.